# Find out what it has the most number

Tags: c#, linq

I need to find out which product has been purchased most frequently, however, if there are several who have such acquisition iphone bought 5 times and 4 times then they just all together. then it just all of them.

```
RepeaterTop3List.DataSource = db.orderlists.OrderByDescending(i => i.qty).Sum();
RepeaterTop3List.DataBind();
```

That is, in other words, that it must make a top 3 of the items purchased by the most.

Comment: "iphone bought 5 times and 4 times then they just all together" you mean different version of same product by this? Please elaborate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i got it right but i guess you want not only one but all most purchased products in case of ties. Use `GroupBy`:

```
r topSeller = db.orderlists
    .GroupBy(o => o.qty)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
    .First();
```

This contains one group with one or multiples.